# how to write sender and receiver for common-mq in nodejs?

Tags: node.js, rabbitmq

I am very new to nodejs. I need to send a message to rabbitMQ using common-mq module. I have installed this package by using the below command

```
npm install common-mq
```

I am not able to write the sender and receiver using this. Can anyone please help me in writing the sender and receiver using nodejs?
        var commonmq = require('common-mq');
        var connect = commonmq.connect('amqp://localhost:5672/queue');

How do I proceed after this?
sender.js looks like below

```
 var commonmq = require("common-mq");

 var queue = commonmq.connect('amqp://localhost:5672/queue', {    implOptions: { defaultExchangeName: '' }});

 var msg =JSON.stringify("Hello world");
 console.log("going for ready");
 queue.on('ready',function () {
 console.log("inside event");
 setTimeout(function() { queue.publish({ task: 'take out trash' }); }, 1000);
 });


 //queue.publish({ task: 'sweep floor' });


 queue.on('error',function(err){
   console.log("error is:"+err);
 });
```

The receiver code goes like this

```
 var commonmq = require("common-mq");
 var queue = commonmq.connect('amqp://localhost:5672/queue', {   implOptions: { defaultExchangeName: '' }
 });
 queue.on('message', function(message) {
   console.log('Got a new message', message);
 });
 queue.on('error',function(e){
    console.log("errrorrr ",e);
 });
```

No messages are received. Please suggest me where am I messing up the things?

Answer (score 0):

After you setup the service, you can listen for new messages or send new ones.

**Receiver:**
The receiver listens on a queue and performs actions based on the messages:

```
//setup the service
var queue = commonmq.connect('amqp://localhost:5672/queue');

queue.on('message', function(message) {
  console.log('Got a new message', message);
  //do something
});
//listen eventually on other events (error, ready)
```

**Sender**:
The sender publishes new messages. Even a receiver could do it...

```
//setup the service
var queue = commonmq.connect('amqp://localhost:5672/queue');
queue.publish(yourMessageAsObject);
```

There are a few other events you could listen to (for example in case of errors). Just check the manual on the [npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/common-mq) site.

Comment: I have tried with that. can you suggest with someother thing?

Comment: @ashok: did you get an error or what happened? This is, as it is described in the docs

Comment: No I did not get any error . I can see in rabbitmq logs that the connection is happening . But not receiving any message . I guess the publish is not working.